# Is there a way to incorporate shiny tag in mutate

Tags: r

I am trying to incorporate shiny tag inside mutate. But unfortunately it is not working

```
asd <- data.frame(a = c("A","B"))
asd <- asd %>% mutate(new = span(a))
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `new`.
x Input `new` must be a vector, not a `shiny.tag` object.
i Input `new` is `span(a)`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred
```

Expected output

```
asd
a    new  
A    <span>A</span>
B    <span>B</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lapply`/`map` to apply the `span` tag on each value of `A`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- asd %>% mutate(new = map(a, span))
df

#  a     new
#1 A span, A
#2 B span, B 

df$new  

#[[1]]
#<span>A</span>

#[[2]]
#<span>B</span>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I do not think this solved. When i try ````datatable(df,escape = F)````, it does not give shiny tags...... Is there no way to get the expected output?

Comment: My code gives the expected output that you have shown in your question. Your question does not mention anything about `datatable` so I don't know what you are referring to.